# About Using Crucible as a Code review tool in an organization

Tags: review, atlassian-crucible

In my organization we are planning to use crucible as code review tool, if we do that, did crucible team will have access to our repositories and code? Is it safe or not using it?

So, I know that Crucible actually should deploy in Organization network. Want more details about it?